# Is there an easy to use vector/matrix/quaternion math library in pure C?

Tags: c, math, opengl

I realize that there are several c++ libraries, but I would greatly prefer C. I found this, but it appears to be for Mac only: https://github.com/rsebbe/CeedMath

Comment: I wrote one in pure C called [Hypatia.](https://github.com/dagostinelli/hypatia/blob/master/src/quaternion.c)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(Shameless self advertisement) You may be interested in my [linmath.h](https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h). Be warned though that I update it only occassionally and some parts may still contain weird bugs. Please report anything you may find.

Comment: That's some good-quality code in my opinion.

Comment: @VictorZamanian: Is this so? I just found a couple of bugs yesterday, will upload a fixed version today, or so.

Comment: It might have bugs, but I like the design approach to the library as a whole.

Comment: Congrats @datenwolf that is a pretty neat little header -- exactly what I've been looking for -- and works quite well! Thanks!

Comment: @datenwolf why have you opted for returning results through a pointer passed in as a function argument?

Comment: @JBeurer: You mean instead of returning the result by value? For the simple reason that you can't return plain arrays in C. You'd have to wrap them in a struct and this is something I intended to avoid, because then addressing a matrix column vector would have become awkward. Also the rules on how structs are returned from functions in the various C calling conventions cause quite some overhead. With all the functions being static inline and the array parameters being pointers there's a lot of wiggle room for the compiler to optimze.

Comment: @JBeurer: If the parameters and return value were structs due to the pass by value nature of C the compiler would have to assume that modifications to the paramter values would not "leak" outside thereby forcing the occassional copy.

Comment: @JBeurer: There's one function in the whole thing that I'm not happy with and that's the matrix inversion code. It's using the determinant inversion method which is prone to round-off error and inefficient. I'll have to replace this with a Gauss-Jordan solver eventually. QR or LR decomposition would be overkill though.

Comment: @datenwolf thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @datenwolf does that mean there is no way to optimize away the *occassional copy*, even with the most aggressive optimization options?

Comment: @JBeurer: Well for strictly inlined code and where parameters are declared thoroughly `const` the compiler can optimize it away. Also in most inlined code after transforming the AST to single register assignment form it's certainly optimizable. The question is how well optimizers do this. Pointers have their own share of optimization caveats (aliasing). That being said, for some reason people seem to be scared of pointers. And personally I don't understand why newbies have so much trouble with them. I found them to be one of the easier things to grasp.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [gsl](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) for your math operations, and [gmp](http://gmplib.org/) for arbitrary precision numbers. They are both cross platform, gnu c libraries that are highly optimized for speed and have support for many types of operations.

Cheers,
Ned

Comment: Btw, here is some candy. I threw together a quick vector implementation for c. https://www.sol-union.com/Resources/Temp/

Comment: Hm, gsl seems pretty verbose and huge. Also it's GPL. While that isn't technically a problem right now, I'd rather not. I found this here in the process of looking for good C libraries, I found this nicety: http://cqrlib.sourceforge.net/ .. for quaternions! :) I also figured that MacOS is pretty much Linux, especially since it's just C math code, so I'll probably use CeedMath from my own post. But thanks, I appreciate the suggestion and it made me find that quat library

Comment: @Blub: MacOS is *not* pretty much Linux. It's pretty much FreeBSD with a different kernel and some (IMHO) sub-par UI system on top.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this, seems to be the most complete. Can't speak for its quality yet obviously: https://github.com/Kazade/kazmath.git

There is also this, seems pretty old (I found code from 2002), but that doesn't mean it's bad: Meschach

Answer (score -3):

And why no one mentioned the [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/) lib?It is header only math library for OpenGL.

Comment: because I need a C library, not C++